# Android Textview Showing Null in output

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting a problem in android textview.
I am simply setting text on the android textview like below

```
            pAmount.setText("Rs." + receiptAmount + "/-");
```

but is showing null in the text

```
                System.out.println("receiptAmount ====>"+ receiptAmount );
```

I had tried to print the value of receiptAmount to check whether, the value is null or not.
But, It is showing the right value in the log.
What is the issue does any body have any idea. 
similarly , other texview are showing the null value in the same activity.

Comment: edit your question with full code

Comment: The reason receiptAmount is null. You need to post the code for this.

Comment: Please post your full code, and is receiptAmiunt a string,int, etc.

Comment: I have passed value of receiptAmount in a method and have referenced it with a static string variable
Both the passed value and referenced values are not null but none of them are getting set on TextView

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView pAmount= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);
```

1.Call the set text After Declaring the above line in Oncreate.

2.get the Proper data in receiptAmount. Your Problem Solved

```
pAmount.setText("Rs." + receiptAmount + "/-");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void FeeGetFeeTypes(String studentId, String fee_slotid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> arrayList_FeeType=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList_FeeTypeAmount=new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    final String MY_QUERY = "select * from feetype where student_id=? and slot_id=?";
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{ studentId, fee_slotid });
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast() == false){
        arrayList_FeeType.add(res.getString(res
                .getColumnIndex(FEE_TYPE_COLUMN_FEETYPE)));

        arrayList_FeeTypeAmount.add(res.getString(res
                .getColumnIndex(FEE_TYPE_COLUMN_FEETYPEAMOUNT)));
    }
    if(arrayList_FeeType.size()>0){
        PrintActivity.sendFeeType(arrayList_FeeType, arrayList_FeeTypeAmount);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code that is resulting the null values. When the data is large, I get **out of memory exception**